# How would one say "always learning in Latin?"

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, translation-check

I'd like to translate the phrase "always learning" into Latin.

I think it would be something like SEMPER DISCENS, but am not sure...

What is the proper translation?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Your translation is correct in a sense, yet the best translation may depend on who is/are learning and other details. Any further detail you could provide would help

Comment: I was thinking "(I am) always learning," or (We are) always learning.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what is implied by the Marine's motto SEMPER FIDELIS.

Comment: _Semper dicens_ is the motto of [Kean University](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kean_University).

Answer (score 3):

Semper discens ist totally right. If you want to express that *you* are always learning, it might make sense to add ‚sum‘. To my mind, a translation using a participle is probably the best way to say it as it gives you the attribute that you are always learning, which is indeed something like a character trait. If you just said ‚Semper disco‘, it does not really clearify that this sentence is meant as a leitmotif - just like you would not say „I always learn“ in English.

Comment: Hm... do mottos generally take the vocative case?

Comment: Yes, I would say so as they are always something like an attribute you have. You do not only live in accordance to your motto but always in general, just like you can have brown hair.